# Typescript: Union types

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda

I am working on setting up union types and have got a few question around typescript union types

**Input**

```
const data = {<json>} // could be Event bridge structure or SQS/SNS event structure
processData(data)
```

Typescript Questions:

```
// example 1
const processData = async (event: EventBridgeEvent<any,any> | SQSEvent) => {
//type casting done here to resolve the issues
}
```

In example1 I have setup union types but this seem to not work as expected. If I call processDate() it looks for sqs event structure in the input even though I have specified OR
I looked another stackoverflow post where they say to setup typeof conditionals but I cannot do typeof for aws-lambda types so this doesn't work for me either. Type casting seems to fix the issue but if union types works as expected, I dont need to do casting right?

Thanks!

Comment: [Please ask a single primary question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

Comment: Since you are going to handle these two types of events which have a distinctly different structure you'd probably need to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to know which type you're actually getting each time.

Comment: I see so type guard is the way to go then -  sounds good thanks!!